# What is a good balance between strong sudo password and a long delay

Tags: security, sudo, password

I am really bad at remembering long passwords (but i can remember short random ones very well) and that is why i would prefer to be able to use password that are relatively short, but I'm afraid those would lower my system's security.

In order to increase security over a short password for `sudo` I wanted to increase the delay between failed attempts.

What would you consider a good guidelines for setting up the delay of sudo in pam relative to the passwords length?

Do you consider this method to be problematic/unsecured or where do you think it can fail.

If it is problematic what would be a better alternative to fight hard to remember long passwords.

(the computer in hand is not a server and does not allow any kind of remote accesses with ssh/rdx or such, i use it as my personal desktop)

Comment: Hmm...  Doesn't `sudo` usually just use the password for your "normal" account?  So if you remember your normal password, you also got the password needed to become root with `sudo`. 
 Yes, you *can* set a root-password and use `su`, but that doesn't involve `sudo`.  If you decide to use `su` be sure to restrict which users can use `su` - either by config of `su`, or by limiting execution-rights.  Problem with `sudo` is that if your user-account password is weak, so is the one needed to become root - and if they first crack your normal account, they can also `sudo` from it.

Comment: I'd suggest memorizing a *good* password for your user-account - and then use it to authenticate `sudo` also.  If it's a short password, you probably should add a longer delay on your normal log-ins too, not just when using `sudo`.  As for `sudo`, unless you use it very frequently, I guess you could add a *very long* retry delay, without it being too irritating for yourself.  Besides, `sudo` "remembers" the password for a little while, so if you use `sudo` twice 5-10 minutes apart, you'll only need to enter password once.

Comment: @BaardKopperud the default configuration of sudo is indeed to use your normal password, but you can change that in PAM configuration.

Comment: @jNull, what are you using to modify the delay? You mention PAM, which module?

Comment: @ilkkachu i dont know much about pam but i came across [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/877385/how-can-i-lower-the-delay-after-incorrectly-entered-login-and-sudo-passwords?newreg=292b111202d043cd9d64688859ba9179) askUbuntu answer

Comment: Note that if someone can touch your computer, then they can get in. E.g. remove hard disk, boot via usb or cd, … . You also have to make it physically secure.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiI4uuW_d_SAhWhK8AKHd7SAZ0QtwIIHzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3NjQ9b3pgIg&usg=AFQjCNECBcD9EW6FnV8zI5F6oK-EMOY7xA&sig2=HbNQarz66d0HOnftIFS3wQ

Comment: @jNull, ah, `pam_faildelay`. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't double check the implementation<sup>(*)</sup>, but if the delay set by `pam_faildelay` gets implemented as a simple sleep, it will cause a single login attempt to take a longer time (thus annoying the user), but will *not* in itself limit the *number* of simultaneous login attempts.

This somewhat undoes the intent of the delay, since someone trying to brute-force your password could simply open hundreds or thousands of login attempts simultaneously. Mostly they would spend their time sleeping, so the load on the system might not even be noticeable.

What you need to do, is to limit the *rate* of login attempts, not the duration of a single attempt. For a network service, I'd suggest limiting it on the network side (say with `iptables` on Linux), but I don't have a solution to give for PAM.

(The policy side of this, the password lengths and time limits, might be more suited to [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).)

<sup>(* Because I didn't have the time. The delay appears to be set through PAM, and might go to the application to implement. But it's unlikely to be implemented as a busy loop, and any program that implements rate limiting)</sup>

Comment: i might should have made it more clear, I'm mainly worried about a program run by a user that can use sudo that has some evil code in it rather then a remote attacker.

Comment: @jNull A malicious program executed by a user with sudo rights is game over, changing sudo parameters won't make any difference. The program can plant malicious code on the user's account that will stealthily trigger the next time the user uses sudo for some legitimate purpose. A non-root trojan can be discovered in theory, but in practice it's highly likely to escape unnoticed.